# Controlling ID sequences but accepting custom IDs without repeating

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to suggest an ID for an order form that should not be repeated (Prefix + sequential number).
The issue is that the user can also type his own ID.

Since the table is quite big, I thought about creating an auxiliar table with just the last suggested ID and prefix, so that it's lighter and easier to search for a new number.

---

Example:

```
Suggested: 20-001   
Suggested: 20-002  
User typed: EX901
User typed: 20-004 (!)
Suggested: 20-003
Suggested: 20-005 (!)
User typed: 20-002 (Invalid)
```

---

I think that I could create a table and a sequence to manage the IDs:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE OrderIdSequence
       START WITH 1
       INCREMENT BY 1;
GO;

CREATE TABLE dbo.Order_Ids (
    ID_Order_Ids int IDENTITY(1, 1) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    Prefix varchar(3) DEFAULT ('') NOT NULL, --Current year as YY.
    Suggested varchar(4) DEFAULT ('') NOT NULL, --Number generated by the sequence.
    Typed varchar(255) DEFAULT ('') NOT NULL, --User typed ID.
    Used BIT NOT NULL Default 0
)
ON [PRIMARY]
```

When the user types an ID that already exists as prefix + suggested number, I will validate when saving the form.

My issue is how to get the next sequential number, skipping if it already exists as 'Typed' column:

Prefix (current year as 'YY') + '-' + Sequence.

Is it possible to have an insert getting the next sequence, with a check if the number already exists?
Perhaps a store procedure would work better?

### What I managed to create:

Not sure if it's the best way, but here's my procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[SuggestOrderProcedure] AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @sequential int = 0;
    DECLARE @prefix varchar(3) = '';
    SELECT @prefix = FORMAT(GETDATE(), 'yy-');

    -- searches for a sequential number that is not being used.
    WHILE @sequential < 1 Or (Select Count(*) FROM Order_Ids WHERE RTRIM(LTRIM(Typed)) = CONCAT(@prefix, RIGHT('0000' + @sequential, 4))) > 0
    BEGIN
       SELECT @sequential = NEXT VALUE FOR dbo.OrderIdSequence;
    END

    -- Inserts the suggested ID into the table Order_Ids.
    INSERT INTO Order_Ids (Prefix, Suggested) OUTPUT Inserted.ID_Order_Ids, Inserted.Prefix, Inserted.Suggested VALUES(@prefix, RIGHT('0000' + @sequential, 4));
    return
END
```

Strange is that when executing via `Dapper`, the `Suggested` column returns without leading zeros.

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion is the following process.

First, create an identity column for the table.  The default id should be a simple number -- nothing more, nothing less.

Second, allow users to specify an id, but it is an *alternate* id.  It can be anything the user wants, except for a number.  You can enforce this with a `check` constraint.

Third, store the alternate ids in a separate table, that looks something like:

```
create table alternate_ids as (
    alternate_id varchar(255) primary key,
    user_id int,
    constraint fk_alternate_user foreign key (user_id) references users(user_id),
    constraint chk_alternate_id check (alternate_id like '%[^0-9]]%')
);
```

When you query a user, you will need to check the alternate ids, if you have a string, and the `user_id` if not.  Alternatively, you could populate `alternate_ids` with a string representation of the `user_id` for each user with no alternate.

Comment: The problem is that the Order ID that the user types can be a number too. My issue is to make the Select to bring the correct generated ID.